# filter on basis of selected option Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a select list which populates states name of united states

`<div class="form-group">
    <select ng-model="state_select" ng-options="f.name for f in state_select | orderBy:'name'"></select>
</div>`

Now I have a table which is populated as follows:-

`<tr dir-paginate="user in users|orderBy:['state_name','fullname']|filter:{user.state_name:state_select.value}|itemsPerPage:10" pagination-id="byState"> 
    <td> <img src="{{user.party_name}}" style="max-height: 10%;max-width: 10%;"/> </td> 
    <td>{{user.fullname}}</td> 
    <td > <img src="{{user.chamber_type}}" style="max-height: 8%;max-width: 7%;"/>{{user.chamber_name}} </td> 
    <td>{{user.district_name}}</td> 
    <td>{{user.state_name}}</td> 
    <td>  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</button></td> 
</tr>`

I just want those entries to be selected where the state name is same as the above select option value. I wrote the filter part but it is giving me some errors. I just want filter on the basis of state name only. Can some one please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote your filter wrong. Change your filter to following.

```
filter:{state_name:state_select.value}
```

Comment: Now the error is gone but the filter does not do the intended task i.e. it still displays all the results.

Comment: @Anirban the filter should be working. I guess something gone wrong in the `state_select.value` you set. Try hardcode any state string eg: `filter: { state_name: 'stateName' }` and refresh your page

Comment: @Anirban i have made amendment on my answer. try again with the code.

Comment: If I hardcode its working for that value...how can I get the selected item value then in the place state_select.value

Comment: I tried with the modified thing you wrote but now my table is not displaying any value.

Comment: @Anirban does it filter value when you hardcode the statename?

Comment: Got my error...your earlier answer was correct I have set my select as follows: {name:"ALASKA"} so basically I dont have a value field...I just had to change it to select_state.name and it started working...thanks for your help...please revert your answer back

Comment: @Anirban have revert my answer back

Answer (score 2):

You wrote your filter is wrong, don't need 'user'

Try this,

```
filter:{ state_name : state_select.value }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in filter 
Can you try the below code

```
filter:{state_name:state_select}
```